# Problem with NMinimize and NonlinearModelFit

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, parallelization

I have data points of some experiment and system of ODE, that approximate this data.

```
data = {{0, 0}, {2.5, 0}, {20, 455.295}, {27, 693.52}, {48, 
    1521.57}, {72, 1557.94}};
k4 = 1;
k5 = 0.0395;
OD = {m'[t] == -a*m[t] - b*v[t]*m[t]  ,
    v'[t] == c*i[t] - k4*v[t]*m[t],
    i'[t] == b*v[t]*m[t] - k5*i[t],
    m[0] == 10^5, v[0] == 0, i[0] == 10^3};
```

Then i have three cells:

1

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[OD, {m, v, i}, {t, 0, 80}, {a, b, c}];
model[aa_, bb_, cc_] := v[aa, bb, cc] /. sol;
```

2

```
fitted = NonlinearModelFit[
   data, {model[a, b, c][t], 0.4 < a < 0.51, 0.8 < b < 1, 
    0 < c < 0.1}, {a, b, c}, 
   t, {Method -> "NMinimize", Method -> "DifferentialEvaluation"}];
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[fitted[t], {t, 0, 80}]]
```

3

```
Clear[Fi, cp]
Fi[aa_, bb_, 
   cc_] := (model[aa, bb, cc][data[[1]][[1]]] - 
      data[[1]][[2]])^2 + (model[aa, bb, cc][data[[2]][[1]]] - 
      data[[2]][[2]])^2 + (model[aa, bb, cc][data[[3]][[1]]] - 
      data[[3]][[2]])^2 + (model[aa, bb, cc][data[[4]][[1]]] - 
      data[[4]][[2]])^2 + (model[aa, bb, cc][data[[5]][[1]]] - 
      data[[5]][[2]])^2 + (model[aa, bb, cc][data[[6]][[1]]] - 
      data[[6]][[2]])^2;
cp = Table[0.01 + j, {j, 0, 2, 0.1}];
Table[{cp[[i]], 
  Part[NMinimize[{Fi[a1, b1, cp[[i]]], a1 > 0 , b1 > 0 }, {a1, b1}], 
   1]}, {i, 1, 2}]
```

So, when i evaluate first cell and then third, Wolfram`s output is:

```
{{0.01, 5.42636*10^6}, {0.11, 5.38385*10^6}}
```

And this result is incorrect.
But if i evaluate simultaneously first and second cell, third cell give me correct result

```
{{0.01, 38702.}, {0.11, 38702.}}
```

So, i do not understand what happened.
I noticed this problem, when i tried to use ParallelTable, i do not know why, but when i use it, wolfram gives me incorrect results.

Comment: The constraints in second and third cell are different, that's why the results differ I think!

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann, I am not comparing the outputs of the second and third cell, so it does not matter what constraints are .I have different output data of the third cell when executing the second, and it changes in the right direction and I don't understand why it works like this.

Comment: MMA version 13.1 Windows 10. I always get {{0.01, 5.42636*10^6}, {0.11, 5.38385*10^6}} from the third cell with and without cell 2.

Comment: @Daniel Huber, if you evaluate all cells simultaneously after quieting kernel, you will get the same result?

Comment: Also, if you run first and third cells, second cell can`t Minimize in a right way :))

Comment: @Daniil Udalov Now I always get the second result.  Very strange, second cell should have no effect. I would report it to support@wolfram.com

Comment: @Daniel Huber, Thank you, send an answer when you get it

Comment: I meant you should report it to Wolfram.

Comment: @Daniel Huber, Oh, sorry, thank you for that suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simplify first cell to

```
(* cell 1*)
model = ParametricNDSolveValue[OD, v , {t, 0, 80}, {a, b, c}];
```

and change third cell to

```
(* cell 3*)
Clear[min]
min[cc_?NumericQ] := {cc,NMinimize[{# . # &[Map[ model[a, b, c ][ #[[1]] ] - #[[2]]   &, data ]],cc == c}, {a , b, c }][[1]] }
cp = Table[.01 + j, {j, 0, 2, .1}];
Map[min , cp[[1 ;; 2]]]
```

evaluation of cell 1&3 and cell 1&2&3 give the same result

```
{{0.01, 38702.}, {0.11, 38702.}}
```

Comment: Thanks! It really works, even with ParallelMap, but i do not understand, what is the problem?

Comment: @DaniilUdalov You're welcome! Me too I don't know the reason, I' ll think about it.